# Combine results of two different records in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL data stored in a single table but with different type and I want to combine the result in one liner show in the example below. Anyone can give suggestion to this SQL query?

My SQL query to get this results:

```
SELECT NumValue, Label, Type
FROM (CustomPollerStatusTable
      INNER JOIN CustomPollers ON (CustomPollerStatusTable.PollerID = 
                                   CustomPollers.CustomPollerID)) 
INNER JOIN Nodes ON (CustomPollerStatusTable.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID)
WHERE ((Nodes.Caption = 'fqdn') AND 
       (CustomPollers.Type = 'Student Info') AND 
       (CustomPollerStatusTable.NumValue > 89) AND  
       (NOT (CustomPollerStatusTable.Label LIKE '%.snapshot%')) AND
       (NOT (CustomPollerStatusTable.Label LIKE '%aggr%')) AND
       (NOT (CustomPollerStatusTable.Label = '/vol/scratch/'))
      )


====================================
NumValue | Label     |    Type
====================================
90       | Student 1 | Student Info
10       | Student 1 | Student Class
====================================
```

The results that I would like to achieve:

```
========================================================================== 
NumValue.Info | NumValue.Class | Label     | Type.Info    | Type.Class
========================================================================== 
90            | 10             | Student 1 | Student Info | Student Class
==========================================================================
```

Comment: What is the combining factor? is it the Label?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it. Slightly different from nrathaus' answer. Obviously you can use `as` to change the column names to whatever you want.

```
select
    s1.NumValue,
    s2.NumValue,
    s1.Label,
    s1.Type,
    s2.Type
from Student s1 inner join Student s2
on s1.Label = s2.Label
where s1.Type like '%Info'
and s2.Type like '%Class'
```

**EDIT:** Now that you have posted your select statement I think this might not work. Can you post the table structure?

**EDIT2:** This might work.

```
INSERT INTO TempTable(
    NumValInfo,
    Label,
    TypeInfo)
SELECT
    c.NumValue,
    c.Label,
    p.Type
FROM (CustomPollerStatusTable c INNER JOIN CustomPollers p
ON (c.PollerID = p.CustomPollerID)) 
    INNER JOIN Nodes n
ON (c.NodeID = n.NodeID)
WHERE n.Caption = 'fqdn'
AND p.Type = 'Student Info'
AND c.NumValue > 89
AND NOT (c.Label LIKE '%.snapshot%')
AND NOT (c.Label LIKE '%aggr%')
AND NOT (c.Label = '/vol/scratch/')
AND p.Type like '%Info'

UPDATE TempTable set
    NumValClass = c.NumValue,
    TypeClass = p.Type
FROM (CustomPollerStatusTable c INNER JOIN CustomPollers p
ON (c.PollerID = p.CustomPollerID)) 
    INNER JOIN Nodes n
ON (c.NodeID = n.NodeID)
    INNER JOIN TempTable t
ON t.Label = c.Label
WHERE n.Caption = 'fqdn'
AND p.Type = 'Student Info'
AND c.NumValue > 89
AND NOT (c.Label LIKE '%.snapshot%')
AND NOT (c.Label LIKE '%aggr%')
AND NOT (c.Label = '/vol/scratch/')
AND p.Type like '%Class'

SELECT * FROM TempTable
```

Comment: Hi @Pat, can you rewrite my SQL query based on your suggestion?

Comment: @webdev.gk Try the stuff I just posted. You will need to make a temporary table to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do:

```
SELECT tblInfo.NumValue AS `NumValue.Info`, 
       tblClass.NumValue AS `NumValue.Class`,
       Table.Label AS Label,
       tblInfo.Type AS `Type.Info`,
       tblClass.Type AS `Type.Class`
FROM (Table)
LEFT JOIN Table AS tblInfo ON tblInfo.Label = Table.Label ON tblInfo.Type = 'Student Info'
LEFT JOIN Table AS tblClass ON tblClass.Label = Table.Label ON tblClass.Type = 'Student Class'
GROUP BY Table.Label
```

Comment: Can you explain how this will force the JOINs to match _different_ rows on one column, i.e. one "Student Info" row with one "Student Class" row? Bonus points for the strangest JOIN syntax.

Comment: First of all, why are you performing 3 joins?, you only need 2 (you also shouldn't use implicit joins). The bacticks on the aliases is for MySQL, use `[]` for SQL Server. Your query will multiply the resultant rows, since there is no grouping

Comment: Hi @nrathaus. I updated the question to include my SQL query to get the results.

Comment: hi @HABO i just updated my question to include the SQL that I used to get the results.

Comment: I like doing three joins because I can :], now seriously, by having `table` and adding data to it, it would make it easier for the user (OP) to do a search for something, otherwise the search would be confusing to write, do you search tbLClass or tblInfo?

Comment: Sorry was a bit egg-nogged when I wrote the original SQL :p

Comment: guys can you rewrite my SQL based on your suggestion? thanks.

Comment: You SQL does `CustomPollers.Type = 'Student Info'` but it returns also Student Class, how is it possible?